# LLVM IR calling and linking printf or any external C function in a portable way

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I created a very simple LLVM IR code piece via the API. Inside the main block, I want to insert calls to functions that are available in the C standard library such as `malloc`, `printf` or some other ones that I write in C by myself.

```
; ModuleID = 'main.d2'
source_filename = "main.d2"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0"

define i32 @main() {
  %1 = alloca i32
  store i32 0, i32* %1
```

**insert call here**

```
  %2 = load i32, i32* %1
  ret i32 %2
}
```

---

I compile the bitcode with

`llc -filetype=obj -o main.o main.bit`

and link the objects with

`clang main.o -o main`

commands.

### Questions

- Do I need to link C stdlib in the last step with compiler flags and/or do I prepare a wrapper library in C which includes the functions I need in order to compile something like `clib.o` for external linkage? Is the second command the proper way for linking such external dependencies?
- Also, how is it going to behave on Windows (I'm on Mac or Ubuntu right now) if I use the same approach? What should change in my workflow?
- Am I missing something here that makes the whole problem irrelevant?

**My machine:**

```
clang version 7.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-7.0/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing something here that makes the whole problem irrelevant?

Yes, you are using `clang` for linking. It knows how and when link C runtime and all these `crt` things. You can even pass textual IR to `clang` directly.

Comment: Is this true even when I don't do something equivalent to `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` in my code or in the commands above? If so, why do we do includes in C if they are automatically added by clang? Sorry for the noob questions.